# Suitable data structure

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing, data-structures, kdtree

I have a **Image** (appx 1000 x 1000) and a set of small images each 10 x 10.

I created a (3 dimensions tree) for storing the HSL values of each tile.I get an array-list of tile RGB values that is closest to the HSL of a particular grid in the target image.

The problem is I don't know to which smaller image that particular HSL in the array list belongs to. I have a **small image class** which stores Number of times the small image was **reused**. I need to access these fields to determine which tile I could use.

Is there a way I could take the array-list of small image HSL that I got and get the small image information.

Comment: The idea of a KdTree is to store an object (tile) at each node.
But note: the result will probably not be satisfying if you do not look into the color distribution inside one tile.

Comment: By storing an object how can I split the tree.

Comment: The node of a KdTree must at least contain:

* some reference to one of the objects you are structuring (pointer, index, ...)
* pointers to heads node of "left" and "right" subtree.

Furthermore the node should contain the axis (0, 1 or 2) which was used for splitting into "left" and "right" - but this can also be derived from the depth. Furthermore it may be helpful to have also a pointer to the parent node.

Comment: And this is the procedure to construct your KdTree: take the median tile with respect to the (average) intensity of red of your tiles and create the head node from it. Then partition your tiles into the ones with lower and higher red values and construct the "left" and "right" subtrees by doing the same with the intensity of green and recursively so on ...

Comment: The better way to go is to derive your tile class from `KdTree.XYZPoint`. Then you do not need to change the KdTree implementation. Note that the KdTree you reference is specified to work on any class derived from `KdTree.XYZPoint`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [KdTree you referenced](http://code.google.com/p/java-algorithms-implementation/source/browse/src/com/jwetherell/algorithms/data_structures/KdTree.java) works on any class derived from `KdTree.XYZPoint`. So the elegant way would be to either derive your tile class from `KdTree.XYZPoint` or create a new class derived from `KdTree.XYZPoint` that has a reference to the corresponding tile object.

Comment: Hey coproc is it ok if you can remove the Hyperlink reference to the KD tree implementation in your answer:)

Comment: For what reason? My answer does not make sense without the referenced implementation. And actually I think the same holds for your question. You should not have removed the link from your question again.